# What is correct to store UpdatedAt or ExpireAt timestamps to limit updates by timeout

Tags: database, design-patterns, database-design, architecture

I need to implement function to store some value with limit on updates once per week.
I'm implemented in following way:

```
class Example
{
    //Stored in db
    public int _value;

    //Stored in db
    public DateTime _updatedAt;

    //Stored in db
    public DateTime _canUpdateAfter;

    //Constant in code
    public TimeSpan _updateTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
        
    public void StoreValue1(int value)
    {
        if (DateTime.Now - _updatedAt < _updateTimeout)
        {
            return;
        }

        _value = value;
        _updatedAt = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public void StoreValue2(int value)
    {
        if (_canUpdateAfter > DateTime.Now)
        {
            return;
        }

        _value = value;
        _canUpdateAfter = DateTime.Now + _updateTimeout;
    }

}
```

I have two ways of implementing it:

1. Store updated time in db and calculate if timeout is passed in .net code.
2. Store value when timeout expire in db and compare it with current in .net code.

Which to use and why?

Answer (score 0):

Both solutions are valid.

The only difference between the ways is the time to decide to set the possibility of the next update.

With solution 1 you make the decision every on code evaluation, with others you force the decision on the past.

I prefer solution 1; is more flexible, and sustainable.

Keep in mind the case of your business change update frequency. With solution 1 are enough new code deploy or change one row of your hypothetical configuration table, whereas whit solution 2 you will need to update all rows of the table.